# MVP, generics and DRY

Tags: c#, generics, mvp, dry

I have a problem with my MVP structure that is built upon generic presenters, views etc. and I feel I'm violating DRY and I dont know how to get around it.

Example.

```
public class Presenter<TView, TModel>
  where TView : IView
  where TModel : Model
{}
```

So far everything is fine, but I want to have it like this

```
public class Presenter<TView, TModel>
  where TView : IView
  where TModel : Model
{}

public class Model<T>
{
  public T Value { get;set; }
}
```

But that won't compile because the where for Model needs a generic parameter.
The fix:

```
public class Presenter<TView, TModel, TModelType>
      where TView : IView
      where TModel : Model<TModelType>
    {}
```

And it's here I feel i violating dry, take for example

```
public class MyPresenter : Presenter<IMyView, MyModel, string>
{}

public class MyModel : Model<string>
{}
```

I feel uncomfortable specifying the string type twice, at the presenter AND at the model,
I only wan't to specify that the presenter is using MyModel as Model, I don't care what type of Model (generics). One solution is to remove the generic constraint for the model but then I can't create a generic Model class hierarchy that I want.

Am I thinking wrong about the whole MVP/generics stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, this would be solved with a typedef -- which C# doesn't really have.

```
public class Model<T>
{
   typedef T TModelType; // this doesn't exist in C#
   public T Value { get;set; }
}
```

Then,

```
 public class Presenter<TView, TModel>
  where TView : IView
  where TModel : Model<TModel::TModelType>
{}
```

There is a type aliasing that you can do with using

```
using NewName = any_type<even_generics<with_generics>>
```

But it's file based -- you can't use it in a class.

I would probably do it like this

1. rename `Model<T>` to `ModelOf<T>`
2. Make a Model base class for `ModelOf<T>` (`ModelOf<T> : Model`)
3. Use  `where TModel : Model`

Model itself will be useful to define the interface methods that don't depend on TModelType.

Comment: Nice, but instead of base Model i defined a IModel interface.

Answer (score 1):

Working with similar solution for my Unity game. Here is my take on MVP architecture. Waiting for your tips to help me  improve my code)
I still not sure if it's OK that I have two empty interfaces and that my View creates both model and presenter in Awake()

## IModel

```
public interface IModel
    {
        
    }
```

## IView

```
    public interface IView
    {
        public virtual void OnInit() { }
    }
```

## IPresenter

```
 public interface IPresenter
    {
        
    }
```

## BaseModel

```
public class BaseModel<TP> : IModel
        where TP : IPresenter
    {
        public TP Presenter { get ; set; }

        public BaseModel() { }

    }
```

## BaseView

```
 public class BaseView<TP> : MonoBehaviour, IView
        where TP : IPresenter
    {
        public TP Presenter { get; set; }

        public virtual void OnInit(){ }

    }
```

## BasePresenter

```
public class BasePresenter<TV, TM> : IPresenter
        where TV : IView
        where TM : IModel
    {
        public TV View { get; set; }
        public TM Model { get; set; }

        public BasePresenter(TV view, TM model)
        {
            View = view;
            Model = model;
            View.OnInit();
        }
    }
```

## BoardModel

```
 public class BoardModel : BaseModel<BoardPresenter>
    {
        public BoardModel() : base () { 
            
        }
    }
```

## BoardView

```
 public class BoardView : BaseView<BoardPresenter>
    {
        public int RowsNumber => meshRenderers.Length;

        [SerializeField] private MeshRenderer[] meshRenderers;
        public override void OnInit()
        {
            foreach (var renderer in meshRenderers) {
                renderer.enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void Awake()
        {
            Presenter = new BoardPresenter(this, new BoardModel());
        }

        public void OnLineSelected(int index) {
            for (int i = 0; i < RowsNumber; i++)
            {
                meshRenderers[i].enabled = index == i;
            }
        }
    }
```

## BoardPresenter

```
 public class BoardPresenter : BasePresenter<BoardView, BoardModel>
    {
        public BoardPresenter(BoardView view, BoardModel model) : base(view, model) { }
    }
```